# Apex:Detail Error on ownership change

Tags: visualforce

We have overwritten the standard page for one of our objects. It directs to a routing page which calls an apex class which then returns a pagereference to either one of two pages. One of these pages is a visualforce page made to mimic the standard page by using the apex:detail command. However, when ever I try and change the ownership it periodoically returns a "Id value is not valid for the sObject standard controller". Any reason why the apex:detail page is producing these errors.

RML Router page

```
<apex:page standardController="rm__RM_Lead__c" extensions="rmlPageRouterController" action="{!PageRouter}" />
```

RML router Controller

```
public class rmlPageRouterController {

    private final rm__rm_lead__c rml {get; set;}

    public rmlPageRouterController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.rml = (rm__rm_lead__c)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference PageRouter() {
        // Variable
        PageReference Page = Null;
        Id profileId = userInfo.getProfileId();
        String profileName = [SELECT Name FROM Profile WHERE id = :profileId].Name;

        // Logic
        If (profileName == 'Customer Service w/ Scripting') {
            Page = new PageReference('/apex/customerservice?id=' + rml.id);
        } else {
            Page = new PageReference('/apex/rmldetailpage?id=' + rml.id);
        }

        Return Page;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code would be helpful

Comment: Mimic Detail Page <apex:page standardController="sObject" > <apex:detail/> </apex:page> On the page, after it has rendered, I'll select the change owner link and attempt to change the owner. When I hit save, the URL cannot retrieve the Id and produces the "Id value is not valid for the sObject standard controller" error.

Comment: I've placed the code above. I feel it might be an issue with the override parameter placed into the URL when choosing to override the standard page with a visualforce page.

Comment: Is your issue still valid? The question says `invalid for sObject controller` but the code you posted is not using sObject as the standard controller like your comment above is using....

Comment: I used sObject to protect the name of my object, but then I decided I didn't care. The error is actually "Id value is not valid for the rm__rm_lead__c standard controller".

Comment: Gotcha. I did not think u could use sObject as a controller. Maybe you can but regardless glad we got that clarified. For future if you make something up in your code use something not real or at least indicate it was made up by using brackets for example. Will prevent a lot of false answers or comments

Comment: normally a page action would call `page.setRedirect(true);` before `return page;` - that could be why apex:detail is confused